# How to modify two or more fields in document by single command

Tags: go

I am trying to add 20 points to two fields inside document with findAndModify through Go (mgo for mongo)

like

```
change := mgo.Change{
        Update: bson.M{ "$inc": bson.M{ "score": 20 } },   // here I need  to add 20 to hist_score also
        ReturnNew: true,
}



collection.Find( bson.M{ "_id": id } ).Apply( change, &doc )
```

How to through one apply update two fields score and hist_score ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official mongo documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc) is very good. The way you use `$inc` for several fields is:

```
{ $inc: { <field1>: <amount1>, <field2>: <amount2>, ... } }
```

And

> To specify a field in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation.

So, basically, change your update spec to something like:

```
bson.M{ "$inc": bson.M{ "score": 20, "hist_score": 10 } }
```